# how to access array in Post request with http client laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-http-client

i have this function to store data from a blade form:

```
$store = Http::withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => $token,
    ])->post('http://example.com/api/Order/', [
        'Key' => 1167722,
        'No' => "12",
        'TL' => [
            'Dtl' => "",
            'Code' => "Screw Hex",
            'IsDetail' => true,
            "DTL" => [],
            ]
            ]);

            return $store;
```

and this is what the response return:

```
{"Key":1167722,"No":"12","TL":[]}
```

and nothing is saved inside TL array i tried wrapping TL array with json_encode() and still no luck and i tried

```
'TL[Dtl]' => 722,
```

and it didn't store as well

Comment: Do you mean that `TL` is empty in the response or in the incoming request? Because if `TL` is empty in the response the problem is not yours but of the server that gives you the response.

Comment: when i try to send data from the above function using http client it doesn't store anything inside [TL] but when i send it using postman or guzzle data will be stored inside [TL]

Comment: Try with
`'TL' => json_encode(['Code' => "Screw Hex",])`

Comment: i tried it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
'TL' => array ([
        'Dtl' => "",
        'Code' => "Screw Hex",
        'IsDetail' => true,
        "DTL" => [],
        ])
        ]);
```

added `array()`